# Anaconda (Jupyter) don't see previously installed package from the file <.tar.bz2>

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, mxnet, bz2

I try to work with Anaconda3-2019.07. I've installed mxnet library from file <.tar.bz2> in offline. I did so because of server which I use hasn't internet connection. For this I entered:

conda install --offline mxnet-1.2.1-h8cc8929_0.tar.bz2

The package was successfully extracted in folder which I can see, but when I enter "help("modules")" to see the installed libraries, mxnet is absent. The same situation appears when I enter "pip list". However when I enter "conda list" in Anaconda Promt, "mxnet" is in the list (but channel is unknown).
Problem lies in the fact that the library is not work.

How is it possible to correctly install <.tar.bz2> package in offline mode?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to install the package offline. But you can copy it from another machine.

`mxnet` is a meta package that installs `libmxnet`, `py-mxnet`. These two packages also depend on other packages. In my test, 31 packages need to be installed in total.

The only practical solution is to create an environment with `mxnet` on another machine and copy the whole environment to your offline machine.

1. create an env with `mxnet` on a machine with internet connection,

   ```sh
   # create an env named as "myvenv"
   conda create -n myvenv --copy mxnet
   ```

   `--copy` is used to

   > Install all packages using copies instead of hard- or
   >                       soft-linking.
2. Find the env location.

   ```sh
   conda info
   ```

   The first value of "envs directories" is where "myvenv" is located. Go to the directory and find the folder named "myvenv". Pack the folder into an arvhive.
3. Copy the archive to the offline machine. Unpack the content to the "envs directories".

Comment: I think "*impossible*" is a bit strong, but I agree on practicality. Most of the dependencies are already in `anaconda=2019.07`, however, they'd have to manually track down the missing dependencies and install them first. As for your solution: they might want to look into [the conda-pack tool](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) which is specifically designed for packing envs.